# UICollectionView glitches on scroll when I try to insert items

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I implement a feed feature using a collectionView. I create the layout of the collectionView using compositional layout.

My collection view consists of 4 sections and my 4th section displays 4 different cells based on the content that is returned from Backend.

I first register each of the cells using the following code:

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: cellType.className, bundle: nil)
self.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellType.className)
```

className is simply an extension added on NSObject and its value represents a class name as string value

I then create my layout this way:

```
let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.width
let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(collectionViewWidth), heightDimension: .estimated(433))
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(collectionViewWidth - 46), heightDimension: .estimated(433))
let groupItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [groupItem])
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 23, bottom: 0, trailing: 23)
```

The `433` in this case is supposedly the maximum height a cell can reach in this section but the height of some cells can be as little as 137. All cells have the constraints adjusted so that the height can be estimated based on the content.

The problem I face is when I try to paginate the collectionView. Here is what I do:
I use the willDisplay function of the collectionView to know when I have reached the end of the available content.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if indexPath.row == feedItems.count - 1 && !isLastPage {
getCommunityFeed()
}
}
```

Then I call an endpoint to retrieve the next page of content and once the data is retrieved, I insert the cells into the collectionView. I do so on the main thread.
The problem here is that my collectionView glitches, the scrolling is not at all smooth and the scrollview jumps upwards once the insert operation occurs. Even after the data is inserted into the collectionView, the scrolling behavior of the collectionView is generally glitchy while scrolling upwards or downwards within the collectionView.